# Insert image uri into gridview

Tags: java, android, baseadapter, android-gridview

I'm trying to display images from db with gridview, but its just won't work, and there is no errors.
The code is ok cuz when i'm reaplcing the line

```
Glide.with(context).load(images.get(position)).into(imageView);
```

with line `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.photo);`
its work fine.
It's seems like there problem with the uri, but the uri is fine, im using the same uris in other places.

```
public class PhotoPreviewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<String> images;
private Context context;

public PhotoPreviewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> images){
    this.context = context;
    this.images = images;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if(images == null){
        return 0;
    }
    return images.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return images.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.grid_item, parent, false);
    }
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image_view);
    //imageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File(context.getFilesDir(), images.get(position))));
    //Uri uri = Uri.parse(images.get(position));
    Glide.with(context).load(images.get(position)).into(imageView);
    //imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.takephoto);
    //Toast.makeText(context, "" + images.get(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return convertView;
}
```

}

```
public class Photo_preview extends AppCompatActivity {

private SQLiteDatabase db;
private Cursor c;
private int frontImgCol, sideImgCol, backImgCol;
private GridView gridView;
private PhotoPreviewAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_photo_preview);

    DbHelper dbHelper = new DbHelper(this);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);

    c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DbHelper.measuresTable.MEASUREMENTS_TABLE + " ORDER BY " + DbHelper.measuresTable.COL_DATETOSORT + " DESC", null);

    frontImgCol = c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.measuresTable.COL_FRONTIMG);
    sideImgCol = c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.measuresTable.COL_SIDEIMAGE);
    backImgCol = c.getColumnIndex(DbHelper.measuresTable.COL_BACKIMG);

    ArrayList<String> images = new ArrayList<>();

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {
        images.add(c.getString(frontImgCol));
        images.add(c.getString(sideImgCol));
        images.add(c.getString(backImgCol));
    }

    adapter = new PhotoPreviewAdapter(this, images);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

}

Comment: Could you share an example of a uri that's not working, there might be an issue with the format of the uri

Comment: file:///storage/emulated/0/1506112776661.jpg

100% ok, cuz if im trying to display the same uri in an imageView its work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Glide.with(context)
     .load(Uri.parse(images.get(position)))
     .into(imageView);
```

Or this

```
Glide.with(context)
         .load(Uri.fromFile(new File(images.get(position))))
         .into(imageView);
```

Comment: doest work, you can see in the code in the comment im alredy try this